# Weird pixel values from OpenCV Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, pixel, scalar

I'm trying to extract pixels from an OpenCV `Mat` object. When I extract them as `Vec4b`, it works nicely, but when I use a `Scalar`, which is the standard (afaik), then I get weird numbers. How to use `Scalar` and interpret the numbers correctly?

Code for extracting pixel (0, 0), once as `Vec4b` and once as `Scalar` (which is in fact a `Scalar_<double>`):

```
cv::Vec4b vec = stroke.at<cv::Vec4b>(0, 0);
printf("vec: %i, %i, %i\n", vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]);
cv::Scalar sca = stroke.at<cv::Scalar>(0, 0);
printf("sca: %5.1f, %5.1f, %5.1f\n", sca[0], sca[1], sca[2]);
```

Output:

```
vec: 223, 178, 77
sca: -91331626426359316704088074967484318223735050578187982644502863694523413598032925912253837118690612448172200441235555626964757579094862898778997953403371230682094365379726071857064466448183314663075981261984082516073752896735112503485663679145991425485597914964276617645535969580912538709979773360278601728.0, ...
```

I'm expecting some creamy yellow color, so I think that the `Vec3b` is correct.

Comment: How is `stroke` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `.at<_Tp>()` function to work correctly, you must specify the component data type of the image matrix correctly. If you lack to do so, the binary data of the pixel is misinterpreted and you get unexpected results.

After you extracted the pixel value correctly, you can convert it to any other generic `Scalar_<_Tp>` type you want. Usually, you convert it to `Scalar`, which is in fact an alias for `Scalar_<double>`. The conversion is implicitly done by using the assignment operator (`=`).

More details:

Most image matrices come with type code `CV_8UC4` (4 channels, red, green, blue, and alpha). E.g. when you load a color image from a JPG file, then the image matrix will be of this format. The `8U` means "8 bits per channel, unsigned integer" and the `C4` means "4 channels per matrix element". The corresponding C++ type of the elements is `Scalar_<uchar>`. You have to specity this to the generic `.at<_Tp>()` function to make it work:

```
mat.at<Scalar_<uchar>>(y, x)
```

After the correct extraction of a `Scalar_<uchar>`, you can automatically convert it to `Scalar` (which is in fact `Scalar_<double>`) simply by assignment:

```
cv::Scalar scalar = mat.at<cv::Scalar_<uchar>>(0, 0);
```

Comment: You saved my life. every where just say 3D image and Vec3b. mat.at<Scalar_<uchar>(y, x) for 4d image .

Answer (score 3):

Well this is interesting:

For grey scale you would normally use `cv::Scalar` like so:

```
Scalar myColor = stroke.at<uchar>(Point(x, y));
std::cout << myColor.val[0] << std::endl;;
```

For `3-channel` colored image you would need `cv::vec3b` like so:

```
Vec3b myColor = stroke.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) std::cout << myColor.val[i] << " ";
```

As the name suggest ( as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28mathematics%29)) a scalar is a single unit not a vector unit. Which can be confusing with the documentation shown [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html). But what you can do if you must have your you values as a `cv::Scalar` type, you could just assign each `vec3b` index to its own scalar. i.e:

```
cv::Scalar b = vec[0];
cv::Scalar g = vec[1];
cv::Scalar r = vec[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info so far. I just to try to stick with some standard, because that's usually the best way to go. I read that pixel values are usually passed around as Scalar, so I tried to do this. If this is not the best way for color images, then I should not use Scalar.

Comment: Doesn't your last example completely defeat the idea of the Scalar class to contain all information about a (color) pixel?

Comment: So when writing this I always assumed that `Scalar` cannot be used as a multi dimensional type. But reading the documentation over I guess it can be used up to 4d. But it does mention that it is derived from the `vec` class so I guess it is up to you if you want to use it.

Comment: Calling a multi-dimensional thing a scalar came indeed unexpected to me, too. Guess we have to deal with this kind of stuff in OpenCV.